# How to combine the values of two different tables with the same attributes

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working with a project which includes to display the `carid(foreign key from tbl_vehicle) reg_num(registration number or plate number of a car, from tbl_vehicle)` and `amount(from tbl_fuel)`, I successfully display the values of `carid`, `reg_num` and `amount` from the table `tbl_fuel` and `tbl_vehicle` in HTML form using this SQL statement.

```
$Withdraw = query("SELECT tbl_fuel.carid,tbl_vehicle.reg_num,sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', '')) + 0.0) as amount
                   FROM tbl_fuel
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_vehicle
                    on tbl_fuel.carid=tbl_vehicle.carid
                    GROUP BY carid");
```

but I forgot that there is another table named tbl_maintenance with the same attributes to tbl_fuel, which are `carid(foreign key from tbl_vehicle)`, `amount`. 
I need to display the values of this attributes from`tbl_fuel` and `tbl_maintenance`in single HTML form.

this is my html form

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <h3 align="center">Withdrawal Per Vehicle</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Plate Number</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($Withdraw as $w): ?>
                <?= '<tr>' ?>
                    <?= '<td>' . $w["carid"] . '</td>' ?>
                    <?= '<td>' . $w["reg_num"] . '</td>' ?>
                    <?= '<td>' . $w["amount"] . '</td>' ?>
                <?= '</tr>' ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

note that the codes stated above runs properly, my question is, what SQL line should be added to my current SQL statement to include attribute's value from tbl_maintenance and display it in my HTML form and group the carid of tbl_maintenance and tbl_fuel and sum the amount from tbl_maintenance and tbl_fuel?

Comment: apply this query $Withdraw = query("SELECT tbl_fuel.*,tbl_vehicle.*,sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', '')) + 0.0) as amount
FROM tbl_fuel 
LEFT JOIN tbl_vehicle
on tbl_fuel.carid=tbl_vehicle.carid
GROUP BY carid");

Comment: carid is exist in your 2 tables ?

Comment: thank you for your reply, but this is not wotking,

Comment: plz share your table structure carid is exist in your 2 tables ??

Comment: @MohammadMalek yeah carid is my foreign key of tbl_fuel and tbl_maintenance these two tables have the same attributes, carid and amount. the code stated in my questions run properly but, i need to include the attribute's values from tbl_maintenace and add them automatically since their attributes are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch it around, make tbl_vehicle the main table, and do sub-queries for the sums:

```
SELECT v.carid,
       v.reg_num,
       IFNULL(f.sum_amount,0) + IFNULL(m.sum_amount,0) AS amount
FROM tbl_vehicle v
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT carid,
          sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', ''))+0) sum_amount
   FROM tbl_fuel
   GROUP BY cardid) f ON f.carid = v.carid
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT carid,
          sum(trim(replace(amount, '$', ''))+0) sum_amount
   FROM tbl_maintenance
   GROUP BY cardid) m ON m.carid = v.carid
WHERE f.sum_amount IS NOT NULL OR m.sum_amount IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: its not working, runs no error but it displays all values from tbl_vehicle with zero amount values.

Comment: @N-Jay, try it now, I included the `trim(replace())` situation had going on, because I realise now that the amount column you have isn't an `int` or `float`, it's a `string` with a dollar sign prefixed.

Comment: what is the meaning of letter v in line 4? is it the tbl_vehicle? or i just have to write letter v?

Comment: `v` and `f` and `m` are table aliases, basically a nickname for a given table that you can use instead of having to write out the whole table name every time you reference it.

Comment: thank you for your codes sir, it runs and  it gets all values and sum automatically, but there one issue, it also display all carid that has not been stored with amount.

Comment: I added a where clause, that should hopefully take care of it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! IT WORKS PROPERLY!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_fuel.carid,tbl_vehicle.reg_num,sum(trim(replace(tbl_fuel.amount, '$', '')) + 0.0) as FuelAmount , sum(trim(replace(tbl_maintenance.amount, '$', '')) + 0.0) as MaintenanceAmount
FROM tbl_fuel 
LEFT JOIN tbl_vehicle
on tbl_fuel.carid=tbl_vehicle.carid
LEFT JOIN tbl_maintenance 
on tbl_maintenance.carid=tbl_vehicle.carid
GROUP BY carid
```

Comment: negative, it only displayed the values from tbl_fuel and the amount value is zero.